# XSLT 1.0 Rearrange specific descendant / child notes to the same level of the parents / ancestors

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm searching for a general approach to rearrange some specific descendant to the level of their ancestor nodes.

What is important:

- I need a general template which works for `p` and `x`.
- The order of nodes `a b DEEPSPACENODE` (from up to bottom) should not be changed as much as possible.

My input:

```xml
<root>
    <p>
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a><DEEPSPACENODE/></a>
        <b>3</b>
        <b>4</b>
        <a>5</a>
        <a>6</a>
        <b>7</b>
    </p>

    <x>
        <a>8</a>
        <a>9</a>
        <b>10</b>
        <b>11</b>
        <a>12</a>
        <a>13</a>
        <b>14</b>
    </x>    
</root>
```

My desired output:

```xml
<root>
    <p>
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a/>
    </p>
    <DEEPSPACENODE/>
    <b>3</b>
    <b>4</b>
    <p>
        <a>5</a>
        <a>6</a>
    </p>
    <b>7</b>

    <x>
        <a>8</a>
        <a>9</a>
    </x>
    <b>10</b>
    <b>11</b>
    <x>
        <a>12</a>
        <a>13</a>
    </x>
    <b>14</b>
</root>
```

Thank you for your help. I tried to solve it myself but I was not succesful.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a more general and flexible solution that can be used in a wide variety of XML documents.

Comment: Also added an XSLT 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a more generic solution that can produce the wanted result without imposing any restrictions on the XML document** -- we don't suppose any pre-defined level of nesting, or that an element named `b` is present:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kFollowing"
   match="a[preceding-sibling::*[1]
                              [self::a]
           ]"
   use="concat(
         generate-id(
                preceding-sibling::*[not(self::a)][1]
                    ),
         generate-id(..)
               )
         "/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[a]">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "a[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::a])]">

   <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select=
   ".|key('kFollowing',
             concat(generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[1]),
                    generate-id(..)
                   )
          )"/>

   <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"
     select="$vGroup"/>
   </xsl:element>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vGroup/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a" mode="group">
  <a>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::*)]"/>
  </a>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "a[preceding-sibling::*[1]
                       [self::a]
    ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <p>
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a>
            <DEEPSPACENODE/>
        </a>
        <b>3</b>
        <b>4</b>
        <a>5</a>
        <a>6</a>
        <b>7</b>
    </p>
    <x>
        <a>8</a>
        <a>9</a>
        <b>10</b>
        <b>11</b>
        <a>12</a>
        <a>13</a>
        <b>14</b>
    </x>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <p>
      <a>1</a>
      <a>2</a>
      <a/>
   </p>
   <DEEPSPACENODE/>
   <b>3</b>
   <b>4</b>
   <p>
      <a>5</a>
      <a>6</a>
   </p>
   <b>7</b>
   <x>
      <a>8</a>
      <a>9</a>
   </x>
   <b>10</b>
   <b>11</b>
   <x>
      <a>12</a>
      <a>13</a>
   </x>
   <b>14</b>
</root>
```

**Now, with the following XML document this solution still produces the wanted result, while the solution by @empo chokes on it**:

```
<root>
   <c>
    <p>
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a>
            <DEEPSPACENODE/>
        </a>
        <z>3</z>
        <z>4</z>
        <a>5</a>
        <a>6</a>
        <b>7</b>
    </p>
    <x>
        <a>8</a>
        <a>9</a>
        <b>10</b>
        <z>11</z>
        <a>12</a>
        <a>13</a>
        <b>14</b>
    </x>
  </c>  
</root>
```

**The same transformation, when applied on the XML document above, produces again the correct, wanted result**:

```
<root>
   <c>
      <p>
         <a>1</a>
         <a>2</a>
         <a/>
      </p>
      <DEEPSPACENODE/>
      <z>3</z>
      <z>4</z>
      <p>
         <a>5</a>
         <a>6</a>
      </p>
      <b>7</b>
      <x>
         <a>8</a>
         <a>9</a>
      </x>
      <b>10</b>
      <z>11</z>
      <x>
         <a>12</a>
         <a>13</a>
      </x>
      <b>14</b>
   </c>
</root>
```

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#all">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[a]">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()"
                      group-adjacent="name() eq 'a'">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"
                         mode="group">
      <xsl:with-param name="pGroup"
                      select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::a]/*"/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a" mode="group"/>

 <xsl:template mode="group"
          match="a[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::a])]" >
   <xsl:param name="pGroup" as="node()*"/>

   <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$pGroup" mode="shallow"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a" mode="shallow">
    <a>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::*)]"/>
    </a>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this stylesheet:

- Group **a** elements by checking the preceding siblings
- Use adjacent recursive templates to aggregate groups of **a**

NOTE I intentionally didn't manage DEEPSPACENODE because is not clear how you want to handle it :P. You can use this transform as starting point.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::b]
        or not(preceding-sibling::*)]">
        <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="adjacent"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a" mode="adjacent">
        <a>
            <xsl:value-of select="self::node()[not(DEEPSPACENODE)]"/>
        </a>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            following-sibling::*[1][self::a]" mode="adjacent"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with output:

```
<root>
   <p>
      <a>1</a>
      <a>2</a>
      <a/>
   </p>
   <b>3</b>
   <b>4</b>
   <p>
      <a>5</a>
      <a>6</a>
   </p>
   <b>7</b>
   <x>
      <a>8</a>
      <a>9</a>
   </x>
   <b>10</b>
   <b>11</b>
   <x>
      <a>12</a>
      <a>13</a>
   </x>
   <b>14</b>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your "starting point" ! `DEEPSPACENODE` is the same as `b`. The only difference: It is a child of a child of `p`. It should be rearranged to the same level as `x` or `p`. Maybe I can manage this myself. Thanks alot.

Comment: Ok, that was clear, but what if it is child of an **a** node which is not last in the adjacents?

Comment: The best is I show you an example: Input: `<p><a><DEESPACENODE/></a><a/></p>` Result: `<p><a/></p><DEEPSPACENODE/><p><a/></p>`

Comment: I see. I can figure out how to achieve that just changing a single template. Can you? Tell me if you can't, but try ;-).

Comment: I will try tomorrow! It is late where I'm living now and I need sleep ;-) But I will give you feedback tomorrow!